# Setup Mock return value without calling underlying service

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

Let's imagine we have `PaymentService` that I would like to test:

```
public interface IPaymentService
{
    int Pay(int clientId);
}    

public class PaymentService : IPaymentService
{
    // Insert payment and return PaymentID
    public int Pay(int clientId)
    {
        int storeId = StaticContext.Store.CurrentStoreId; // throws NullReferenceException
        // ... other related tasks
    }

}

public class Payment_Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void When_Paying_Should_Return_PaymentId
    {
        // Arrange
        var paymentServiceMock = new Mock<IPaymentService>();
        paymentService.Setup(x=>x.Pay(Moq.It.IsAny<int>).Returns(999); // fails because of NullReferenceException inside Pay method.

        // Act
        var result = paymentService.Object.Pay(123);

        // Asserts and rest of the test goes here
    }

}
```

But I'm unable to mock StaticContext class. **I'm unable to refactor this and inject this class via constructor** to `IPaymentService` - this is old code and must remain untouched :(

Is there any possibility to simply return expected result, in my case `999` without calling underlying StaticContext.Store.CurrentStoreId?

**EDIT**: I know that at this moment this test have no sesnse, but I'm wondering if there is way to do this in a way I'm asking. This is only simplyfied version of my problem.

Comment: At that point, what do you think you'd actually be testing? If you mock out `IPaymentService`, you're not testing `PaymentService`...

Comment: Looks like you are exercising mock. What you want to test here?

Comment: Yes, but this is only simplyfied version of my problem. My real PaymentService is used in another parts of my code. I want just to skip Pay method.

Comment: If you're trying to do a partial mock (which is what it looks like) it's a sign you need to break your class out into another class

Comment: Is StaticContext a static class? if yes, Moq cannot mock static class or static method.

Comment: Dariusz, is using a dependency injection framework an option? You can refactor the class to accept the store object in it's constructor and have that resolved by StructureMap with a little set-up. If you really want to test this case you are very likely going to have to refactor *something* as the code is badly designed.

Comment: @DanPantry That's all true, but the problem is that refactoring is not alloved at all. I know how to do it right, but I can't at this moment. So any injections can not be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't test the service using that. Have a look at using [Moles in MSTests](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/593642/The-Moles-Framework) or [Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) for that (if that's an option).

You'll have to create a fake assembly:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    var paymentServiceMock = new Mock<IPaymentService>();
    paymentService.Setup(x=>x.Pay(Moq.It.IsAny<int>).Returns(999);

    // Shim DateTime.Now to return a fixed date:
    System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.StaticContext.Store.CurrentStoreIdGet = () =>  { 1 };
    // Act
    var result = paymentService.Object.Pay(123);
}
```

Comment: Seems like Fakes are only in VS Ultimate? I have professional.

Comment: I think they included it into Professional as of Update4 for VS 2012

Comment: I don't have it and I'm using VS 2012 Professional as well, updated this morning. Seems like it's still only there for '13.

Answer (score 0):

Mock object is a proxy class generated by Moq for interface you are mocking. So, when you are exercising mock object

```
var result = paymentService.Object.Pay(123);
```

You are actually verifying implementation of Moq framework - whether it returns result you setup for mock. I don't think you want to unit-test Moq framework. If you are writing tests for your `PaymentService` class, then you should exercise instance of this class. But it has static dependency inside. So, first step will be making `PaymentService` testable - i.e. replacing static dependencies with abstractions and injection those abstractions into `PaymentService` instance.

```
public interface IStore
{
    int CurrentStoreId { get; }
}
```

Then make `PaymentService` depend on this abstraction:

```
public class PaymentService : IPaymentService
{
    private IStore _store;

    public PaymentService(IStore store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }

    public int Pay(int clientId)
    {
        int storeId = _store.CurrentStoreId;
        // ... other related tasks
    }    
}
```

So, there is no static dependency now. Next step is writing test for `PaymentService` which will use mocked dependencies:

```
[Test]
public void When_Paying_Should_Return_PaymentId
{
    // Arrange
    var storeMock = new Mock<IStore>();
    storeMock.Setup(s => s.CurrentStoreId).Returns(999);
    var paymentService = new PaymentService(storeMock.Object);

    // Act
    var result = paymentService.Pay(123);

    storeMock.Verify();
    // Asserts and rest of the test goes here        
}
```

And last thing is real implementation of `IStore` abstraction. You can create class which delegates calls to static `StaticContext.Store`:

```
public class StoreWrapper : IStore
{
    public int CurrentStoreId 
    {
       get { return StaticContext.Store.CurrentStoreId; }
    }
}
```

Use this wrapper when setting dependencies in real application.

Comment: I agree, but as I've said: I CAN'T refactor this. This is prohibited in my case. Sad but true.

Comment: @Dariusz then truth is - you can't unit-test it with Moq. Only option you have is using framework which allows mocking of static dependencies (but most of them are not free). But better option is trying to refactor this code to make it losely coupled and testable

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IPaymentService
{
    int Pay(int clientId);
}    

public interface IStore
{
    int ID { get; }
    // Returns the payment ID of the payment you just created
    // You would expand this method to include more parameters as
    // necessary
    int CreatePayment();
}

public class PaymentService : IPaymentService
{
    private readonly IStore _store;
    public PaymentService(IStore store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }
    // Insert payment and return PaymentID
    public int Pay(int clientId)
    {
        //int storeId = StaticContext.Store.CurrentStoreId;
        // Static is bad for testing and this also means you're hiding
        // Payment Service's dependencies. Inject a store into the constructor
        var storeId = _store.ID;
        // stuff
        ....

        return _store.CreatePayment();
    }

}

public class Payment_Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void When_Paying_Should_Return_PaymentId
    {
        // Arrange
        var store = new Mock<IStore>();
        var expectedId = 42;
        store.Setup(x => x.CreatePayment()).Returns(expectedId);
        var service = new PaymentService(store);

        // Act
        var result = paymentService.Pay(123);

        // Asserts and rest of the test goes here
        Assert.Equal(expectedId, result);
    }

}
```

Inject an `IStore` object into the `PaymentService` - Using `StaticContext` lies about the `PaymentService`'s dependencies, violates the principle of least surprise (developer tries to use the PaymentService and then realizes they have to do something else after an exception is thrown and some digging that isn't documented in, say, the constructor by injecting a dependency), makes it harder to test (as you noticed, `StaticContext.Store` is null because it hasn't been set), and less flexible.

After that you would tell Store to return a certain value from `CreatePayment` and test that the service returns the same value (which would be the payment ID)

EDIT:

> I'm unable to refactor this and inject this class via constructor to
>   IPaymentService - this is old code and must remain untouched :(

Regarding this comment, the best thing you can do in this case is to set the `StaticContext.Store` value to a faked Store object that returns a hard-coded number and test that... but really, you should refactor this code, because it will make it a lot easier in the long run.

```
// inside test code
// obviously change the type as necessary
// as C# doesn't have ducktyping
class FakedStore
{
   public int CurrentStoreId { get { return 42; } }
}
var store = new FakedStore();
StaticContext.Store = store;

// rest your test to test the payment service
var result = ..
Assert.Equals(result, store.CurrentStoreId)
```